# Excel PivotTable Formatting Values Cells

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

First ever post.  Thanks to all who answer.  Many have learned much from each of you.

Creating PivotTable with VBA.  Want Values Area cells (data and labels) to be; HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter.  Current method;

```
'... typical VBA code to create Pivot table;
'ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create ...
'Dim MyPT As PivotTable
'...
'number format all value cells (done without selecting)
    MyPT.PivotFields("Sum of Bikes").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
'center align all value cells, data & lables (must select cells to do this)
    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    For Each pvtField In MyPT.PivotFields
        If pvtField = "Bikes" Then
            MyPT.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True 
              'The PivotSelect method does not return an object.  It selects a range.
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End If
    Next pvtField
```

Any way to do this without selecting the range via PivotSelect (similar to how number format was applied)?